# Como implementar Navigation Drawer com Mapa em um Fragment

Tags: android

Criei um projeto *Navigation Drawer* no Android Studio aquele que já vem pronto.

Agora em um dos `fragments`, preciso de um mapa com uma localização. Como implementar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Também tive este problema!

Segue abaixo como consegui:

Activity:

```
 public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {


        private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
        private ListView mListDrawer;
        private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity);
            mDrawerLayout = DrawerLayout.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.mDrawerLayout));
            mListDrawer = ListView.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.mListDrawer));


             mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.title_menu_open, R.string.title_menu_close)
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                        super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_menu_open);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                        super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_menu_close);
                    }
                };

                mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mToggle);
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

                openFragment(new MapFragment());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mToggle.syncState();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            mToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
        }


        public void openFragment(final Fragment fragment){
            if(null == fragment) return;
            final FragmentManager mManager =  getFragmentManager();
            if(mDrawerLayout != null){
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            }
            if(null != mManager)
            {
                FrameLayout.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.mContent)).removeAllViewsInLayout();
                mManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mContent, fragment).commit();
            }
        }


    }
```

Fragment:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment
 {


    MapView mMapView;

    GoogleMap mMap;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container, false);
        mMapView = MapView.class.cast(view.findViewById(R.id.mapView));
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (mMapView != null) {
            mMap = mMapView.getMap();
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mMapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }
}
```

Activity.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mDrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:id="@+id/mContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/mListDrawer"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

activity_maps.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mapView" >
</com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Valeu cara pela ajuda....(y)

Comment: Se lhe a resposta lhe ofereceu o que desejava, favor marca-la como correta! Suadações

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski achei sua resposta muito vaga, não está completa, e como fica a implementação do AndroidManifest.xml e da API do Google Maps? e a chave do Google Developers, Keytool com o hash md5? e as dependências lá no Gradle?

Comment: É porque a pergunta é como implementar um Drawer com mapa em uma Fragment. Não como configurar o mapa em si. Se o usuário marcou como correta, talvez a resposta tenha sanado a dúvida! Caso queria, realize um pergunta específica, de como configurar o mapa. Obrigado pela dica!

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski valeu cara, agora eu entendi, mas vale lembrar que toda a implementação só dará certo se você estiver com tudo ok, as dependências, a chave e o AndroidManifest.xml configurados corretamente, e  realmente isso de configurar, dá base para uma nova pegunta.